# writeImage($variable) outputs question mark in filename

Tags: php, imagick

So I'm trying to generate few images via imagick operations.

```
$this->image->writeImage("img/new.jpg");
$this->image->writeImage($location);
```

This code will write me 2 images, the first one is OK, but the second one (`$location` is set to `img/kopanky.jpg`) will create image too, but with name `kopanky.jpg?`. It doesn't matter how I name it, where I place it, but it happens only when I'm using a variable. The second image looks like the first one, but the question mark in the filename annoys me.

I tried `writeImageFile` with `fopen` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your `$location` string contains a special character at the end, which is translated to `?` on save.

To verify this, add a `var_dump($location);` to that part of your code and see what's in the string.

Comment: You're right, it was newline character, which I didn't realized it's here, while parsing some files. Thanks